# non UNIQUE constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique, check-constraints

So, I got in this situation:
I create a table (let say `model_a`), in this table I have 2 cols (let say `col1` and `col2`).
I need a constraint that satisfy this reality:

```
model_a

col1 | col2
-----+-----
  1  |  1  //first row
  2  |  1  >> ok
  1  |  1  >> ok
  1  |  2  >> can not insert this row
```

It's not UNIQUE constraint, you can duplicate the first row.

The only one time this constraint active is `col1` is the same but `col2` is different.

Need help :smile: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first row" in a relational database. Tables represent un-ordered sets.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I don't think the OP means "first row in the table" but simply "first row in the example" where the columns are equal.

Comment: Can you insert 2/1 more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of a unique index on the least/greatest value of both columns, that applies only to rows where the values are not equal:

```
create unique index myidx 
    on model_a (least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2))
    where (col1 <> col2)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5cebfa862c2b499b43b0e027f59dcbbc)**:

```
insert into model_a (col1, col2) values (1, 1); -- ok
insert into model_a (col1, col2) values (2, 1); -- ok
insert into model_a (col1, col2) values (1, 1); -- ok

insert into model_a (col1, col2) values (1, 2);
-- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myidx"
-- DETAIL:  Key (LEAST(col1, col2), GREATEST(col1, col2))=(1, 2) already exists.
```

Comment: I don't feel sample data is enough to make any decision about algo, but looks like when the "first" row is 1, 2 it is allowed to have 2,1. I didn't understand which "sameness" is checked: col1 value of new row with col1 of any "before" row or col1 and col2. Considering the tables like spreadsheet, not an unordered set in DBMS.

Comment: @astentx: the way I understood the question, "first" refers to the order in which rows are added to the table, as shown in my demo. The "first" row could very well be `(1, 2)`, in which case inserting `(2, 1)` later on would not be possible.